# Can we add a <span> inside an <h1> tag?

Tags: html

Is it a proper method to use a `<span>` tag inside an  `<h1>` tag?

```html
<h1>
    <span class="boardit">Portfolio</span>
</h1>
```

I know we can write it in this way...and am also following the below syntax in my own website..

```html
<h1 class="boardit">
  <span>Portfolio</span>
</h1>
```

However, I Just wanted to know the cleaner form of html..

Comment: @fireeyed I think he wants to follow what is right, semantics of the tag I mean.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you wan t

Comment: Putting spans in headings presents issues with word wrapping. Has anyone else observed this?

Comment: Ever tried wrapping any text that's in a span? And how about wrapping text that's in any block element? @Rafael

Answer (score 206):

Yes you can.

[HTML4 has this to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5):

```
<!ENTITY % heading "H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6">
<!--
  There are six levels of headings from H1 (the most important)
  to H6 (the least important).
-->

<!ELEMENT (%heading;)  - - (%inline;)* -- heading -->
```

And [`%inline;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) is:

```
<!ENTITY % inline "#PCDATA | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %special; | %formctrl;">
```

And [`%special;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special) includes `<span>`.

The current [HTML has this to say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html#h1-content-model):

> **Content contents**
>   Phrasing content

And [*Phrasing content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) includes `<span>`.

Comment: The link from "HTML5 has this to say" is broken :(

Comment: @mehulkar Thanks for letting me know, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 37):

Yes you can. It can be used to format a part of a h1 block:

```
<h1>Page <span class="highlight">Title</span></h1>
```

If the style applies to the entire h1 block, I do this:

```
<h1 class="highlight">Page Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's typically fine to use a `span` inside of an `h1`.  `span` is an inline element, so it's typically okay to use it inside anything (that allows elements inside it!)

And there's not really a cleaner way to do it sometimes, say if you want to style only part of the `h1`.

On the other hand... don't do it if it's not necessary, as it is a little ugly : )

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's fine, but why not

```
   <h1 class="boardit">
      Portfolio
   </h1>
```

If thats all you're doing?

Comment: It's not all. The request is to style only part of the heading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The span displays inline, so it should not affect the styling of the H1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use span tag with header tags and there is nothing wrong in it. Indeed this is widely used for styling header tags, specially for coloring a particular word or letter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use span tag with header tags and there is nothing wrong in it. Indeed this is widely used for styling header tags, specially for coloring a particular word or letter.

Answer (score -2):

```
<h1 style="display:inline;">Bold text goes here</h1> 
<span style="display:inline;">normal text goes here</span>
```

Think in above lines - Worked for me - use display:inline prop

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Quentin I believe he meant suggesting to force the heading to be an inline element. A fine idea, if it's doable.

Comment: This answer should not be down voted since it solves the problem although it's not what being directly asked. +1 for the solution.